# General expression for $n$-th derivative of $x^{\alpha}$, $\alpha > 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Assume $\alpha > 0$ is fixed, but not necessarily integer.

I'm looking for a general expression of $$A(n)=\frac{d^n}{d x^n} x^{\alpha} \tag{1}$$

If I'm not messing anything up, with $\alpha > n$, $A(n)=(\alpha)_{n}~x^{\alpha - n} = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha +1)}{\Gamma(n + 1)}x^{\alpha-n}$.

On the other hand, $\alpha < n$, it seems that at a certain point $t$, such that $\alpha - t \geq 0 \geq \alpha - t - 1$, a $(-1)^j$ term pops up for the remaining $n-t$ terms. 
Here for me it's not clear whether we can still use a similar expression through $\Gamma$ functions, and how would it look like?

**My question:** is there a general expression of (1) for any $\alpha$ and $n$?

Sorry if this is a trivial question. I think I could work out the expressions for all 3 cases (the two mentioned and one with $\alpha$ being an integer), but it somehow feels like there should be a general expression, something involving $\Gamma(n - \alpha ) / \Gamma(n - 1)$, but can't seem to reach it.

Comment: Yes, this is called [fractional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Fractional_derivative_of_a_basic_power_function). As for the equation, the denominator actually $\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha-n+1)}$. Try the second derivative of $x^2$, your formula predicts $\frac{\Gamma(2)}{\Gamma(2)} x^0$, when its should really be $2x^0$. It does look like there are separate cases for negative and positive $a$. If $a \geq 0$, then $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} x^\alpha = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha - n+1)}x^{\alpha-n}$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! Yes, it's almost exactly what I was looking for! Though at the wiki it's not clear what happens with large $a$, that is, with $\Gamma(\alpha - n +1)$, when $\alpha < n$ and $\Gamma$ becomes undefined (?).

Comment: There is nothing different about positive and negative $\alpha$, unless $\alpha$ is an integer, in which case $\Gamma(\alpha - n + 1)$ is undefined when $\alpha - n + 1$ is a nonpositive integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derivative(s) can also be expressed via the [Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pochhammer_symbol):
$$
\frac{{\rm d}^n}{{\rm d}x^n} x^\alpha = (1+\alpha-n)_n x^{\alpha-n} ,
$$
where the Pochhammer symbol (representing here the raising factorial) is defined as
$$
(c)_n = c\cdot{}(c+1)\cdots(1+c-n)
$$
for complex $c$ and positive integer $n$.

Comment: Thank you and @guy600 for answers and the proper terminology, was very helpful for further research!